# Shorten the size of db with UTF8 encoding by reducing the size of single character shortage to 1 byte(7 bit)

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8

I need to reduce the size of my sql DB. My db strings are UTF8 encode as it a different language.
2 bytes are allocated for each character, as the language nearly contains 100 characters for representation. How will I convert those 16 bit characters to 7 bit characters to shorten my DB size.

Comment: UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding. Codepoints that only need 7 bits are already stored in a single byte (8 bits).

Comment: We have some dissension about the meaning of your Question. Edit to clarify. Give examples of your text being stored. – Basil Bourque 6 mins ago    Delete

Comment: Is that DB even able to store 7 bit? Boundaries other than "byte" (8 bit) are rare, especially around Java and Android.

Answer (score 2):

> My db strings are UTF8 encode as it a different language. 2 bytes are allocated for each character

> How will I convert those 16 bit characters to 7 bit characters

Nope, that’s a contradiction.

In [UTF-8](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), characters that need only 7 bits ([US-ASCII](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)) take only 8 bits (one octet). UTF-8 uses 1, 2, 3, or 4 octets per character, depending on how large is the character’s [code point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) number.

[UTF-16](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), in contrast, uses one or more pairs of octets per character.

Best to use UTF-8 generally. [UTF-16 is considered harmful](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/102205/34735) by some folks.

Recommended reading: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: No contradiction. The characters of that language take two bytes in utf8 you can read.

Comment: @blackapps The last sentence of the Question suggests otherwise.

Comment: 16 bit is two bytes so that was what was said.

Comment: @blackapps The title also suggests otherwise. I posted a comment asking clarification, as this Question is clearly not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the character set for your langue.

Like it was done in the time you did not use utf yet but that set of one byte per character.